# How to Generate A Map Chart With Curved Lines

Tags: javascript, angular5

How To show A Map Chart With Curved Lines Between The countries?

[image]

Comment: there's the button that shows the source code, is not that enough?

Comment: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-curved-lines/

Comment: that amcharts is not for free , i  want a free version